# How can I add child elements to a custom element in HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I want to create a custom element that's able to host any HTML markup within:

```html
<my-custom-element>
  <p>This is some message.</p>
  <div><button>Click here</button></div>
</my-custom-element>
```

The above markup doesn't seem to work. Every browser renders it like:

```html
<my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
  <p>This is some message.</p>
  <div><button>Click here</button></div>
```

How can I have a custom element contain child elements in markup?

Comment: You will have to put a `slot` tag in the template of the custom element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots

Comment: Chrome renders it as-is

Comment: @Olian04 slots are only needed if shadow dom is used, no?

Comment: it should work. what is the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using shadowDOM then you need to add a `<slot>` into your shadowDOM.

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = '<style>:host{border:1px dashed red;display:inline-block;}</style><slot></slot>';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<my-element>
  <p>This is some message.</p>
  <div><button>Click here</button></div>
</my-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use connectedCallback event

```
customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement{
   constructor(){
      super();
   }
   connectedCallback(){
      this.innerHTML="<p>This is some message.</p><div><button>Click here</button></div>";
      // or this.appendChild(...)
   }
});
```